# Qual a origem da expressão "Oh, pá" de Brasil ou Portugal? Significa oh amigo?

Tags: significado, expressões, interjeições

Qual a origem da expressão "Oh, pá" de Brasil ou Portugal?

Exemplo de utilização: "hó, pá, estás bom?"

É utilizado nos dois países no mesmo contexto?

Comment: Se ninguém ainda fez esta pergunta poderá estar entre as melhores do site.

Comment: Em Portugal se costuma colocar no final da frase: Que eu saiba, não pá. //Vamos embora daqui, pá.///E opa é uma interjeição: 1. [Brasil] Expressão usada para exprimir espanto ou admiração.
"opa", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/opa. E "oh, pá" não é português, na verdade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sou brasileira e creio que a expressão Oh, pá! deve ser uma versão simplificada da frase Oh, rapaz! que dita mais rápido transforma rapaz em pá.
No Rio de Janeiro onde nasci, temos o hábito de fazer a mesma coisa que os portugueses e assim, a frase Oh, rapaz vamos embora! é dita como Oh, rapá vombora!

Comment: Bem-vinda ao Portuguese StackExchange! Uma sugestão, o Priberam diz que “pá” vem de "rapaz", podes pôr isso na tua resposta para fortalecê-la.

Comment: Acho que O rapaz seria diferente de oh pá. Nunca ouvi isso na fala de um brasileira.

Comment: Sou do Rio de Janeiro, aqui vivendo e lidando com todas as classes sociais há décadas. Afirmo que não temos o hábito. de falar "rapá".  Ocasionalment5e algém pode falar, mas reafirmo que: **como hábito, no Rio de Janeiro, nunca**.

Comment: @Centaurus, nem os jovens? Principalmente aqueles que seguem uma moda "favela" e "bandido"? Aqui em SP, é bem comum, principalmente estes. "Ô rapá. Que horas são?"

Comment: @Schilive    Eu não sei o que você entende por bem comum.  Eu já ouvi "rapá", "broder", "simbora", algumas vezes mas não considero "bem comum", nem mesmo quando estou a falar com moradores de favelas.  Quando a conversa é entre dois iguais, há uma tendência ao uso mais frequentes do que chamamos de idioleto, que o cinema e a televisão gostam de explorar para caracterizar bem a classe social dos interlocutores.  Talvez ´por isso tal uso pareça frequente.

Comment: Já a expressão (informal) "ô meu", não é ouvida no Rio, mas parece ser típica dos paulistanos.

Comment: @Centaurus, eu me expressei mal. Onde moro, no Estado de SP, e cidade de São Bernardo do Campo, já ouvi vários jovens dizendo "rapá" como vocativo.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei a origem desta expressão, mas posso dar exemplos de usos em Portugal, onde esta expressão é bem usada (não acho que seja usada muito no Brasil: [vê aqui um comediante brasileiro a brincar um bocado com esta expressão, típica portuguesa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nh_0nS19dI&t=6m39s&ab_channel=TheNoitecomDaniloGentili)).

Exemplos de possíveis usos em Portugal.

1. Oh, pá, já me fodeste a cabeça.
2. Oh, pá, não me chateies.
3. Oh, pá, não sei sinceramente, é uma boa pergunta.

Em inglês eu talvez traduziria estes exemplos como

1. Heeey, you already pissed me off.
2. Dude, don't piss me off. (mas talvez "dude" em inglês seja mais usado pela juventude, enquanto "oh, pá" em Portugal pode ser utilizado um bocado por todos (acho))
3. Hm, honestly I don't know, that's a good question

Portanto "oh pá" é usado um bocado como "hm...", "well...", "huh...", etc., no inglês, mas normalmente quando usas "oh pá" tás um bocado chateado/aborrecido, mas não necessariamante. As vezes, nem precisas do "oh", e podes dizer só "pá, não sei mano" (mano é tipo "bro" em inglês, e é usado mais pela juventude).

Comment: pá in Portugal means guy or dude, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a palavra que você está se referindo na verdade é a "opa", que tem um significado de ficar surpreso com algo. Antigamente era utilizada, por exemplo, como uma forma de expressão quando você vê ou encontra uma pessoa que não estava esperando (não necessariamente de uma forma ruim).Exemplo: "Opa, você por aqui? Tudo bem?".

Mas com o passar do tempo, acabou virando mais uma forma de cumprimentar, utilizada de forma informal, sem necessariamente estar surpreso.

Comment: Olá @leandrofw, bem vindo ao site pt.se. A expressão que refere ["*opa*"](https://dicionario.priberam.org/opa) em uma palavra, é diferente de *"Oh pá"* que são duas palavras, uma interjeição *["Oh"*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/oh) e uma segunda palavra (nome ou interjeição) [*"pá"*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/p%C3%A1).

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo hahaha. Obrigado, não conhecia essa expressão! Não passou pela cabeça pesquisar sobre pois as duas são bem parecidas.

Numa tentativa de acrescentar ao tópico, "oh, pá" não é muito utilizada no geral, mas tem o mesmo significado da minha resposta (palavra "opa"): cumprimentar/chamar outra pessoa.

Comment: Exato, na pergunta está "ho,pá!" será equivalente a Opa?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que na Coreia do sul se usa Opá exactamente como nós.  Sendo os portugueses navegadores que levamos e trouxemos tantos costumes pelo mundo, penso que pode ser uma explicação da origem desse costume ou levamos ou trouxemos.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências.

Comment: É possível adicionar a referencia?

Answer (score -1):

Em Portugal, o termo oh! PÁ, é  simplesmente abreviação de PAtrício, forma como os portugueses se tratam carinhosamente.

Comment: Desconhecia esta forma